# Check if Polymer element is the first of it's kind for parent

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I have a custom element, `x-element`.
When I use this element, if it's the first one of it's type on it's parent I want `margin-top` on an inner element to be `0`, and on all the following it should instead be `1 em`. (value just examples).

I want the element itself to handle this, so I **don't** have to add extra css on every page that I use this element on.

Which is the solution I currently use, like so:

```
<style>
  x-element
  {
    --x-element-margin-top-opened: 1em;
  }
  :host x-element:first-of-type
  {
    --x-element-margin-top-opened: 0;
  }
</style>
```

Which is unreliable in itself with just css, because:

> https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html#style-api
>   Polymer’s custom property shim evaluates and applies custom property **values once at element creation time**.

And the order of which the children are created are not reliable (last could be created first etc)
Which means I also have add code on the parent to updateStyles on all children when all is loaded.

> In order to re- evaluate custom property /../ call the updateStyles
>   method on the element.

***So instead of cluttering every parent with lots of duplicate code, I want everything related to this encapsulated and handled in the element itself.***

The documentation (https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements.html#initialization-timing-for-siblings) I found says the following:

> There are no guarantees with regard to initialization timing between
>   sibling elements.
>
> This means that siblings may become ready in any order.
>
> For accessing sibling elements when an element initializes, you can
>   call async from inside the attached callback:
>
> ```
> attached: function() {
>   this.async(function() {
>     // access sibling or parent elements here
>   });
> }
> ```

I tried this:

```
attached: function() {
    var self = this;

    this.async(function() {
      var c = self.parentNode.children;
      for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        if (c[i].nodeName === 'X-ELEMENT') {
          if(c[i] === self) {
            console.log("isFirst", i, c[i]);
          }
          break;
        }
      }
     });
}
```

but it still fires sometimes before all siblings are actually there, meaning I get the wrong element marked as the first.

I guess what I would like is to attach a listener to the parent that gets a **native** event that fires when all children are loaded, is there something like this, or any other solution where I don't have to add stuff to the parent?

Comment: Are you using a `dom-repeat` or something similar to attach the children? Because if you are, it might be easier to set a specific class to the first children with a computed binding

Comment: Sometimes a `dom-repeat`, sometimes just static html, so yes I could add a class to just the first element, but it then defeats the purpose of the element handling this itself, which I really would like.

Comment: Are the children part of the element definition or are they added in the `<content>` tag?

Comment: No content tag, part of the definition

Comment: Then wouldn't adding a class to the first element with any sort of logic within the element's code count as the element handling this itself? Or do you mean you just want to handle this only using CSS?

Comment: I wanted as little code outside the element as possible.

But it seems that might be hard, so the next best thing would have an event on the parent that tells me when all child's are added, that way I can reliably calculate which is first.